# Meaning of some results of Gauss on cyclotomic numbers.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, math-history, cyclotomic-fields

In an unpublished fragment of Gauss entitled ["on the theory of complex numbers"](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN23599524X?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B391%5D%2C%22pan%22%3A%7B%22x%22%3A0.366%2C%22y%22%3A0.766%7D%2C%22view%22%3A%22toc%22%2C%22zoom%22%3A0.481%7D), written by him around 1810,  Gauss made early inroads into the theory of cyclotomic numbers, which are numbers that can be written as $f(\epsilon) = a_0+a_1\epsilon+a_2\epsilon^2+\dots+a_{n-1}\epsilon^{n-1}$ when $n$ is a prime number and $\epsilon^n = 1$ ($\epsilon$ is a non-trivial root of unity). Just to illustrate its importance, in chapter [I] he proves Fermat's last theorem for $n=3,5$, and in chapter [V] he states the following theorem on "cyclotomic units" later established by Ernst Kummer:

> every unit of the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}[\epsilon]$ is a product of numbers of the  form $$\frac{\epsilon^{\alpha}-\epsilon^{\beta}}{\epsilon^{\gamma}-\epsilon^{\delta}}$$

According to Paul Bachmann, another theorem later established by Kummer (in 1847), which states that a cyclotomic integer $f(\rho)$ whose analytical modulus (analytical norm) is equal to 1 must be $\pm\rho^n$, also occurs here for the first time.

My question is concerned with a result Gauss gives in chapter [III], which posits a certain upper bound for a quantity Gauss calls "mensura" in the case $n=5$, in terms of a quantity he calls determinant $D$. The quantity he calls determinant is defined to be:

$D=f(\epsilon)f(\epsilon^2)\cdots f(\epsilon^{n-1})$

so it is almost the algebraic norm of the cyclotomic number. However, the deeper meaning of the notion of "mensura", which literally means "scale" , is not very clear to me. It is defined to be the sum of analytic norms of $f(\epsilon)$ and all of its complex conjugates except $f(\epsilon^0)$:

$$Mensura = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(\epsilon^k)f(\epsilon^{-k})$$

Gauss states the following inequallity:

> Highest mensura = $2(\frac{sin(2\pi/5)}{sin(\pi/5)}+\frac{sin(\pi/5)}{sin(2\pi/5)})\sqrt{D}\approx 4.472\sqrt{D}$

My question is how to prove this inequlity? and what is the meaning of the notion of "mensura"?

Comment: Did you calculate $D$ and the Mensura for $n=5$? Do you see how the substitution $\epsilon \rightarrow \epsilon ^k$ is acting on the coefficients?

Comment: @CyclotomicField - I calculated and verified most of Gauss's statements in chapter [III], but this particular statement I did not succeed yet to prove... the expression of $D$  for $n=5$ is very long (includes over 100 terms), so I did not write it down...

Comment: While it does have a lot of terms there is a pattern to them and significant simplification occurs. If you find it daunting in full generality try some specific $f(\epsilon)$ with less terms to tackle the problem in pieces. I find it easier to write the roots as $\{\epsilon^{-2}, \epsilon^{-1},1,\epsilon,\epsilon^2\}$ since it keeps the powers smaller at each iteration and highlights the conjugate pairs.

Comment: @CyclotomicField - I wrote $\frac{sin(2\pi/5)}{sin(\pi/5)}$ as $\sqrt{|1+\epsilon|}$ to make the calculations more transparent, but I still I have some troubles even when taking only 2 terms, i.e $f(\epsilon)=a+b\epsilon$. I might solve this problem and prove Gauss's inequality somewhere in the near future, but it might take some time and even if I will eventually succeed, it might not be a very insightful and elegant solution...by the way , do you know how to prove it?

Comment: For $f(\epsilon)=a + b\epsilon$ then $D = \prod_{k=1}^4(a+b\epsilon^k)$. Pair the terms $(a+b\epsilon)(a+b\epsilon^4)=a^2+b^2+ab\epsilon + ab\epsilon^4$ and $(a+b\epsilon^2)(a+b\epsilon^3)=a^2+b^2+ab\epsilon^2 + ab\epsilon^3$. To avoid getting lost lets set $p=a^2+b^2$ and $ab=q$ so that we have $(p+q(\epsilon+\epsilon^4))(p+q(\epsilon^2+\epsilon^3)) = p^2+(pq+q^2)(\epsilon+\epsilon^2+\epsilon^3+\epsilon^4)$. Well, isn't that handy, all the imaginary roots have exactly the same coefficients. Try $2\epsilon + 3 \epsilon^2$ next and then $1+2\epsilon +3 \epsilon^3$ using the same idea.

Comment: @CyclotomicField - meanwhile the only simplification I made is for the case of $f(\epsilon)=a+b\epsilon$: I wrote $D = p^2-pq-q^2$ and $Mensura = 4p-2q$. The constant term $4.472$ is an approximation for $2\sqrt{5}$. However, I still don't get the trick in this inequallity, even for this simplest case of only 2 terms.

Comment: @CyclotomicField - I think I succeeded in proving this inequality for the case $f(\epsilon) = a+b\epsilon$. To prove it, denote the Mensura as $m$; one has to show: $1\le \frac{2\sqrt{5D}}{m}\implies \frac{1}{5}\le \frac {p^2-pq-q^2}{(2p-q)^2}$. By the inequality of means we are restricted to ratios $p/q\ge 2$ or $p/q\le -2$. The global minimum for the function $D/m^2$ is therefore attained when $p=-2q$, and the value of it is $1/5$.